Android Studio String preview replaced by three dots "..."
Using Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.1.3. In my code editor, I can see string resource values previewed like this:

However, in our test classes, only three dots "..." appear instead of the string value preview:

How can I enable string value preview in test files instead of "..."?

press CTRL + Numpad + button to Expand, press CTRL + Numpad - button to Collapse.

It only folds / unfolds it. Basically it will show the string IDs. But I want to see the string value previews.
